# From SQL to HQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I'm having problems with the following query from SQL to Hibernate HQL:

```
select 
    (lot of things from table 1)
from 
    table1 
inner join 
    table2 on table1.investigationEvent = table2.id_investigationEvent 
inner join 
    table3 on table2.eventSection = table3.sectionEventsCod
inner join 
    table4 on table3.sectionEventsCod = table4.investigationSectionEvent
```

In HQL I wrote this:

```
Select blabla 
         + "FROM table1 t1 "
            + "INNER JOIN t1.investigationEvent t2 "
            + "INNER JOIN t2.eventSection t3 , "
            + "table4 t4 
            INNER JOIN t4.investigationSectionEvent t3 "
            + "WHERE iset.typology.idTypology = :idTypology "
            + "WHERE ast.typology.idTypology = :idTypology ";
```

The problem is that with this syntax i can make joins from: 
           table 1 - > table 2
           table 2 - > table 3

but i can't make the join  
table 3 -> table 4

since the table 3 bean doesen't have any attribute to go to table 4 bean. However, is possibile make the contrary:

table 4 - > table 3 (since table 4 contains an attribute table 3 bean)

The problem is: using this syntax i have to call a second FROM (table4, as you can see from my hql query). Can you solve my problem? I have to make the query calling only the first table with FROM then using all JOIN(s).

This is Some Beans:

```
Table 1 {
   ...
   Table 2 investigationEvent; }

Table 2 {
 ...
 Table 3 eventSection
```

and then

```
Table 4{
 ...
 Table3 investigationSectionEvent; }
```

The problem is that Table 3 doesen't contain Table 4.

Comment: You don't use table and table field in hql. You use class and attributes so without your mapping we can't help you.

Comment: If you can't navigate from t3 to t4 you'd either have to try the other way round if possible (i.e. t4 -> t3 -> t2 etc.) or use a cross join like you did, although you'd not need to join `t4.investigationSectionEvent` but check that in the where clause (e.g. `where ...t4.investigationSectionEvent = t3` or `t3 in elements(t4.investigationSectionEvent)`). AFAIK you Hibernate 5.1+ supports more complex joins though, i.e. you should then be able to join t3 and t4 directly.

Comment: Right, add your mapping, but if you have a problems with JOINs in HQL, it is probably problem with that you haven't mapping between Table 3 and Table 4 and then you are not able to create JOIN between them via HQL.

Comment: I can create JOIN from table 4 to table 3 but i have even to call Table 4 with FROM since is not possibile go to Table 4 from Table 3 (but is possible go to Table 3 from Table 4). I can't change the beans and i have to avoid CROSS JOINs.

Comment: Try like this, "select blabla from table t1 join t1.investigationEvent t2 JOIN t2.eventSection t3, table4 t4 where t3.someColumnValue= t4.someColumnValue" and you can add more conditions in where.